# Installing pycuda on google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pycuda

I want to install pycuda on google colab. 
I tried `pip install pycuda` but it gives `WARNING: nvcc not in path. May need to set CUDA_INC_DIR for installation to succeed`

After reading some blog, I also did `!export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH` and `!export CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda` but still it gives the same error.

Also, while terminating installation it also displays

```
In file included from src/cpp/cuda.cpp:1:0:
src/cpp/cuda.hpp:14:10: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
#include <cuda.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: can you add all error?

Answer (score 1):

This script installs the packages that are needed for `pycuda` too:

```
!curl https://colab.chainer.org/install | sh -
```